# How set up OpenVPN WiFi access point?

Tags: wireless-networking, openvpn, wireless-access-point, wifi-configuration, openwrt

Running an OpenVPN client on Openwrt.
Connecting to a VPN service provider.
OpenVPN works great over LAN. 
Want to set up OpenVPN WiFi access point

Tried to simply create an access point and connect to it, but
it gives no internet connection.

Comment: I find your question hard to read and understand. Please rewrite your question with complete sentences so that it is easier to understand what you are actually asking about.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to set up some kind of Wi-Fi network that shuttles users through a VPN to the wide open Internet.

As far as the networking, you'll need to route Wi-Fi to a specialized VPN adapter.  The [gl.inet](http://www.gl-inet.com/) routers have firmware for this same thing, but for Tor instead of a VPN.

You may want to look into [pfSense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PfSense) if you want to dedicate a PC to it.  They talk about setting something like this:

- [Configuring OpenVPN on pfSense](https://www.highlnk.com/2013/12/configuring-openvpn-on-pfsense/)
- [pfSense configuration for routing all traffic via VPN](https://support.hidemyass.com/hc/en-us/articles/202720876-pfSense-configuration-for-routing-all-traffic-via-VPN)

If you want your WAP/router to do this, OpenWRT can probably help you do it, though you will need some Linux skills:

- [OpenVPN Setup Guide for Beginners](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/vpn.openvpn)